# Average by 24 values in an array r

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, apply, netcdf

I have annual data in a large array of dimension 3 named tmp_array [1: 143, 1: 134, 1: 8760], the first two dimensions are relative to the coordinates and the third dimension is relative to the hourly temperatures. I would like to have in the end the average daily temperature (an average temperature over 24 hours) and an array tmp_array [1: 143, 1: 134, 1: 365]. Here is the code that I put in place but I seem far from the account.

```
temp<-apply(tmp_array, MARGIN=c(1, 2), mean)
```

This code seems to give me the average over the year.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you could do this by reshaping your array: `ar = array(..., dim = c(143,143,8760)) ; ar2 = array(ar, dim = c(143, 143, 24, 365)) ;
ar2 = aperm(ar2, c(1:2, 4, 3)) ; rowMeans(ar2, dims = 3 )` or by reshaping and then aggregating: `reshape2::melt(ar)`. But it would be good if you added some data to test -- preferably a small example array, with the expected outcome.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see here you obtain the average temperature over the 8760 hours in a year for each coordinate, a two-dimensional array [143,134].
Would you like to obtain the same result for each day of the year?
In this case you can first create an empty array for storing your results

```
new.array <- array(dim=c(143,134,24))
```

Then you can take the mean of 24 observations in turn along margin 3, so obtaining the average temperature per day.

```
library(abind)
new.array <- array(dim = c(143, 134))
for (i in seq(1, 8760, 24)) {
new.array <- abind::abind(new.array,  apply(my.array[1:143, 1:134, i:(i+23)], MARGIN=c(1, 2), mean), along = 3)
}
dim(new.array)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think what you're proposing is getting closer to what I want but there are still some things to change I think. By executing your code I have in the end this :  new.array[1:143,1:134] instead of new.array[1:143,1:134, 365]. I thought about changing new.array<- array(dim=c(143,134,365)) but I still do not get the desired result.

Comment: I will back to you soon

Comment: The year is not leap year, with this modification, I have what I wanted but with a layer more (366 instead of 365). The first layer is empty, I just deleted it!

Comment: Yes, it was the first empty array.